# What is the basic functioning of group by in SQL?

Tags: sql

What is the behaviour of `group by`?

I have two tables:

```
create table department
(
     dep_id int primary key,
     dep_id varchar(20),
     dep_location varchar(20)
)
```

and

```
create table employees_dep 
(
    emp_id int primary key,
    emp_name varchar(20),
    job_name varchar(20),
    manager_id int,
    hire_date date,
    salary decimal(10, 2),
    commision decimal(7, 2),
    dep_id int 
        foreign key references department(dep_id)
)
```

With data as:

```
insert into department values (1001, 'finance', 'sydney')
insert into department values (2001, 'audit', 'melbourne')
insert into department values (3001, 'marketing', 'perth')
insert into department values (4001, 'production', 'brisbane')

insert into employees_dep 
values (68319, 'kayling', 'president', null, '11-18-1991', 6000, 0, 1001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (66928, 'blaze', 'manager', 68319, '05-01-1991', 2750, 0, 3001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (67832, 'clare', 'manager', 68319, '06-09-1991', 2550, 0, 1001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (65646, 'jonas', 'manager', 68319, '04-02-1991', 2957, 0, 2001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (67858, 'scarlet', 'analyst', 65646, '04-19-1991', 3100, 0, 2001)
insert into employees_dep  
values (69062, 'frank', 'analyst', 65646, '12-03-1991', 3100, 0, 2001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (63679, 'sandrine', 'clerk', 69062, '12-18-1991', 900, 0, 2001)
insert into employees_dep  
values (64989, 'adelyn', 'salesman', 66928, '02-20-1991', 1700, 400, 3001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (65271, 'wade', 'salesman', 66928, '02-22-1991', 1350, 600, 3001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (66564, 'madden', 'salesman', 66928, '09-28-1991', 1350, 1500, 3001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (68454, 'tucker', 'salesman', 66928, '09-08-1991', 1600, 0, 3001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (68736, 'andres', 'clerk', 67858, '05-23-1997', 1200, 0, 2001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (69000, 'julius', 'clerk', 66928, '12-03-1991', 1050, 0, 3001)
insert into employees_dep 
values (69324, 'marker', 'clerk', 67832, '01-23-1992', 1400, 0, 1001)
```

The question: when I write a query as:

```
select  
    d.dep_name,
    count(d.dep_name) as no_of_employees 
from 
    employees_dep e, department d  
group by 
    d.dep_name
```

The output is:

- all the department names with no_of_employees as 14 in all the rows

Why is this so because the group by clause selects one data and make group of it so it should work as select the first department name and then group all the rows in employee table with same department id and then count the no of rows in each group
when i write query as -

```
select  
    d.dep_name,
    count(d.dep_name) as no_of_employees 
from 
    employees_dep e, department d 
where 
    e.dep_id = d.dep_id  
group by 
    d.dep_name
```

Then it returns the correct output with the correct number of occurrences of each department in the table.

Please explain this behaviour of group by....

Comment: Use your first query without the `GROUP BY` clause and selecting `*` and start counting the rows for each department. That should answer why.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: `group by` works exactly as described, which you would see if you looked at the detail data (very first step in troubleshooting). The issue is your cross join

Answer (score 1):

Use inner join. hope this help

select  d.dep_name,
        count(d.dep_name) as no_of_employees 
from employees_dep e 
inner join department d on e.dep_id = d.dep_id 
group by d.dep_name

Answer (score 0):

You much use a joining condition in your first query. Else it will do a cross join. Using proper joining condition will give you the proper output.

```
select  d.dep_name,count(1) as no_of_employees
from employees_dep e join department d  
On e.dep_id=d.dep_id
group by d.dep_name
```

Comment: this will result in a syntax error.  it is a mix of implicit and explicit join syntax.  For explicit the "," should be INNER JOIN which would be preferred.  For implicit (not preferred) the ON condition would actually be in a WHERE clause

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it while copy pasting. Corrected.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using implicit join syntax and are creating a Cartesian Join (Cross Join) which means every possible combination of the 2 tables is then being counted.  So if you have 14 departments every employee will look as if it is in 14 of them.  Researching how to do joins in SQL and use explicit join syntax will help out.  In this case INNER JOIN as others have also pointed out will be the key to correcting the issue.

```
SELECT
    d.dep_name
    ,count(emp_id) as no_of_employees
FROM
    department d
    INNER JOIN employees_dep e
    ON e.dep_id = d.dep_id
GROUP BY
    d.dep_name
```